# integral involving complex, modules and infinite sum

Tags: integration

I want to integrate the square of the module of the following complex function:

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n$$

over the ball $\bar{B}(z_0,\delta)$, i.e.:

$$\iint_{\bar{B}(z_0,\delta)}{|f(z)|^2 dxdy}$$

I proceeded like this, but have some doubts:

1) I make the change $z-z_0 = re^{i\varphi}$, so:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}{d\varphi \int_{0}^{\delta}{|f(z_0+r e^{i\varphi})|^2 r dr}} =\int_{0}^{2\pi}{d\varphi \int_{0}^{\delta}{|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n (r e^{i\varphi})^n}|^2 r dr}} = $$

2) Now, either magic or negligence occur:

$$=\int_{0}^{2\pi}{d\varphi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{|a_n|^2\int_{0}^{\delta}{|r^{2n}e^{i\varphi 2n}|}rdr}$$

3) Now that magic has been done, and knowing that $|e^{i\phi 2n}|=1$ we are left with:

$$2\pi (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{|a_n|^2 \int_{0}^{\delta}{r^{2n+1} dr}}) = 2\pi (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{|a_n|^2 [\frac{r^{2n+2}}{{2n+2}}]}_{0}^{\delta}) = $$

4) And finally:

$$= \pi \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{|a_n|^2}{n+1}\delta^{2n+2}}$$

Which hopefully is the right answer (at least, so it is in my notes).

Despite the guess of step 2 is mine, I don't exactly understand how it should be like that. I find pretty illegal to asume that the module of a sum is the sum of the modules. Why should it be the case here?

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: the magic was that you interchanged sum and module? That is wrong in general due to the triangular inequality, $|x+y|\leq|x|+|y|$, which is one of the defining properties of a norm.

Comment: Yes, that is why I think the step 2 is illegal, but, it is the only path I can find to the solution.

Comment: I assume the solution is OK, since I had it form my textbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your step 2 is incorrect. You instead need to use the fact that for a complex number $w$, the following holds: $|w|^2=ww^*$, where $^*$ denotes complex conjugation. Now apply this to $w=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n (r e^{i\varphi})^n}$ at the end of your step 1, to obtain
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}{d\varphi \int_{0}^{\delta}{|f(z_0+r e^{i\varphi})|^2 r dr}} =\int_{0}^{2\pi}{d\varphi \int_{0}^{\delta}{|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n (r e^{i\varphi})^n}|^2 r dr}} =\int_{0}^{2\pi}{d\varphi \int_{0}^{\delta}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n (r e^{i\varphi})^n}\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{a_m (r e^{i\varphi})^m}\right)^* r dr}}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}{d\varphi \int_{0}^{\delta}}\sum_{m,n}a_n a_m^* r^{n+m+1} dr e^{i (n-m)\varphi}\ .
$$
Now you use the fact that $\delta_{a,b}=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\xi}{2\pi}e^{i\xi(a-b)}$ for $a,b$ integers, where $\delta_{a,b}$ is the Kronecker delta.
Therefore you have
$$
=2\pi \sum_{m,n}a_n a_m^* \delta_{m,n}\frac{d^{2+m+n}}{2+m+n}\ ,
$$
where I renamed the radius of the ball as $d$ to avoid confusion with the Kronecker delta. The Kronecker delta is now killing one of the sums and forcing $n=m$, therefore in the end
$$
=2\pi\sum_n |a_n|^2 \frac{d^{2+2n}}{2+2n}\ .
$$

Comment: Magic is due to Kronecker! Thank you Pierpaolo, I was really stuck here. You saved me!

Comment: You're most welcome.